# How to reference a comboboxes to input values into a query?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How to a get the value of value selected in a combo-box? I have a combo-box called "cndGetUsage" in a form called "frmStationUsage". How do I get the value in the form and check to see if a value was selected?

This are being referenced from a module called mMainOutputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
myval = Me.cndGetUsage.Column(1)
```

or

```
myval = [Forms]![frmStationUsage]![cndGetUsage].Column(1)
```

these will tell you what the current value in the box is.  the columns are because in access your combo box can have multiple columns.  also if you set the bound column then you don't have to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you  populating the list from? It works great if you're using a Select statement, from a table with a unique ID field as a unique key. Your combo box index is zero based. If you have more controls in the form you can use the Recordset Clone and Bookmark statements to move back and forth as you select items from the combo box